# How to do performance tuning of Apache server?

Tags: apache-2.4, performance, performance-tuning

We have an apache server 2.4.X which we are using as a reverse proxy in front of one Java Application . We have enabled Apache status module [Apache Status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) and we are able to see  that number of idle worker threads will always be zero , Hence performance of our application is poor . Our hosting server have **32 cores and 64 GB of RAM** . We are using mpm_worker module of Apache . [Apache mpm_worker](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html) .Our Current mpm_worker configuration is :

```
 <IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit            150
    StartServers             8
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads         75
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

.We went through [Apache performance tuning article](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html) and found that we can have **2930 request workers** as per our server configuration .My questions are  .

1. Changing **MaxRequestWorkers** alone to 2930 will work ?
2. Do we need to change **ThreadsPerChild**  also ?
3. **StartServers** which represents Apache child processes also needs to be changed /Or can we change
   this also for optimum performance based on our server configuration.
4. What should be **ServerLimit** value for updated **MaxRequestWorkers** case which will be 2930 ?

Comment: Why would you expect to have any worker threads on a reverse proxy? Why use apache for this, and not nginx?

Comment: @TomTom Yes that is correct but as we are working in a bank so new package approval is little bit hard to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to create a suiting profile for your Server you need to understand what each Configuration of this Directive means:

- **ServerLimit**
  The maximum Number of Processes that the Server will create
- **StartServers**
  The Number of Processes that the Server will create on Start-Up
- **ThreadsPerChild**
  The Number of Threads that each Process will create
- **MinSpareThreads**
  The Minimum Number of Threads that must exist. (Mostly at Start-Up)
- **MaxSpareThreads**
  The Maximum Number of Threads that the Server will keep running.
- **MaxRequestWorkers**
  Maximum number of connections that the Server will accept simultaneously.
- **MaxConnectionsPerChild**
  The Maximum Number of Connections that each Process will accept. This determines the Time of Life of a Child Process.

Having said this. How many Child Processes are running usually?
Did you already reach the `ServerLimit` of Child Processes?

You should also look at the `MaxClients` Setting that it will admit all the Request that are coming in.

If no Worker Threads are available increase the number of `MaxSpareThreads`

Launching new Child Processes will consume **CPU Cycles** so on a busy Site the `MaxSpareThreads` limit should be big.

But disposing old Processes will also free your **System Memory**, so you should limit the **Time of Life** of the Processes with `MaxConnectionsPerChild`.

On the other Hand **Application Run Time** keeps your Threads busy. Being **faster** with your *Java* Application will free Threads and Memory.

As an Example:
Receiving **50 requests / second** and each Request takes **4 seconds** to complete. you would need **200 Threads** to cover this Demand.
If each Request took only **2 seconds** you could cover it with only **100 Threads**.

Comment: @Budo Hugo Barwich since there is a cap of 150 request workers and ThreadsPerchild  is 25 so currently there are only 6 child process . Since request workers threads are capped adjusted in 6 child processess .CPU usage is always under 10

Comment: if you reached `MaxRequestWorkers` you would be unable to connect to the Site and receive a "_Connection refused_" Response.

Comment: Indicating that your CPU usage is low indicates that the Proxy is not working but rather waiting for the _Tomcat_ Response. Enable in the Logs the `%D` Stats to track the Processing Time of your _Java_ Application. Please refer to this documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Comment: @Deepak How many Request / Second do you receive?  and how long is the Processing Time for each Request?

Comment: Current stats : 150 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers
WRWWRWWRWKKKWWKRKRWKRWWRWRWKWWWRWWKWKKKWRWWKWKWWRWKKRWWWRRWCKWWK
WRRRWWKRKWWKWWWCRWWRKKWWWWWWRWRKWRKWWWRWWRKWKKRWRWWWWRWWWWWWRKWR
WWWWKKKWKRRRWRWWRWWWWK  . Some time for some users we are getting connection refused without any response .   Some of the request to JAVA application are weird and always server use to get those many requests from client to get work from server ,So those kind of requests are constant and we can not stop those Moreever these are 130 in numbers and response time of such requests is 2-3 seconds

Comment: @Deepak 1) Your incoming traffic is far bigger than 150 Requests / Second. 2) from the Hardware profile I conclude that your Proxy Server is mostly empty with low workload. But it can do much more. -> Permit as much `ThreadsPerChild` as you have CPU cores `ThreadsPerChild 32`. As a Proxy Server I suppose your Child Process Size is small thus you can set a high limit on `ServerLimit`. So you can set easily `ServerLimit 1000` and `MaxRequestWorkers 1000`. That way you will be able to see the real usage and traffic volume and do fine adjustments later.

Comment: Thank you for you analysis and feed back , But According to this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html  ** ServerLimit is a hard limit on the number of active child processes, and must be greater than or equal to the MaxRequestWorkers directive divided by the ThreadsPerChild directive.**  Is 1000 will be a safe value for this ? Also What do you think about StartServer directive should it be left to 8 or should be increased .

Comment: Having at your Disposition such a Monster of Server with **65536 MB RAM** and asuming a Process Size of **20 MB per Apache Process** you Server can easily serve more than **2000 Apache Processes** at a time: `$ echo "scale=3; 64 * 1024 /20 *.9"|bc -l
2949.120`. So, 1000 Processes is a safe value. But still you don't know how many Request per Second actually come in. On this Number depends the `StartServer` which is the Number of Processes at Server Start Up

Comment: @Budo Thank you According to server status currently there are 20 requests per second .19.5 requests/sec - 0.6 MB/second - 32.1 kB/request  . Could you please reply to me according to documentation of apache start servers is only on starting of the server and if load increases it will be automatically increased , So i  am planning not to touch StartServer but only ServerLimit and MaxRequestWorkers directive as suggested by you. Also you are correct our server can take 2930 request workers with 18 mb Apache process , bUt we are planning to increase that gradually as this is production

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110493/discussion-between-deepak-and-bodo-hugo-barwich).